# ReLu, PreReLu, Leacky ReLU

Tags: machine-learning

What is the advantages of Leacky ReLU over ReLU?

I have read some research paper but found nothing or more precious answer.
Sometimes found that ReLU and Pre-ReLU helps more model optimization as compared to Leacky ReLU. Why?